# Is there any way to turn a column into a string?

Tags: r, string

For example, if I have a data set

```
data.frame(x = c("a","b","a","b","c"))
```

how can I get a output = 
`a,b,a,b,c` in a `list` or `text`.

Answer (score 2):

`paste(data_frame,collapse=",")` will collapse the column into a single string.

Comment: Hi, if I build a dataset not a list, I get the output:`xx <- data_frame(x = c("a","b","a","b","c"))
paste(xx,collapse=",")`, `[1] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"`, How can I fix this `\`?

Comment: @JiaJia try `paste(xx$x, collapse=",")`

Comment: Thx a lot, it works for me.